# ActiveMQ To Heroku

Tags: java, heroku, jms, activemq-classic

I've been trying for a while now to deploy ActiveMQ as a message broker to heroku but no luck. My java app uses jms obviously, I tried to use RabbitMQ which is supported out of the box from heroku and use RabbitMQ's jms plugin but it is it doesn't support message selectors for queues. 
So it there any way to run ActiveMQ on heroku ?

Comment: Can provide an error message or more details on what behaviors you do see? Also, which addon are you using?

Comment: @codefinger I can't find any add-on the supports jms (for free) so now I uploaded activeMQ bin trying to run it in its own dyno, but now I get (ClassNotFoundException org.apache.activemq.web.webConsoleStarter).